# Assignment to mutable variable interferes with type inference of otherwise valid calculation

Tags: f#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm attempting some Newton Raphson updates. Here is a piece of code that compiles and runs (warning: infinite loop).

```
let thetam = [|beta; sigSq|] |> DenseVector
let mutable gm = grad yt xt betah sigSqh   // returns DenseVector
let hm = hess yt xt betah sigSqh   // return Matrix<float>

while gm*gm > 0.0001 do
    gm <- grad yt xt betah sigSqh
    thetam - (hess yt xt betah sigSqh).Inverse() * gm // unassigned compiles
```

However, as soon as I assign the last value to the mutable variable `thetam` as follows...

```
while gm*gm > 0.0001 do
    gm <- grad yt xt betah sigSqh
    thetam <- thetam - (hess yt xt betah sigSqh).Inverse() * gm // gm here has problems
```

a squigly red line under `gm` appears and the compiler complains `The type 'Vector<float>' is not compatible with the type 'DenseVector'`

However, the function grad is explicitly told to return a DenseVector and ordinarily works as expected.

```
let grad (yt : Vector<float>) (xt : Vector<float>) (beta : float) (sigSq : float) =
    let T = (float yt.Count)
    let gradBeta = (yt - beta * xt)*xt / sigSq
    let gradSigSq = -0.5*T/sigSq + 0.5/sigSq**2.*(yt - beta * xt)*(yt - beta * xt)
    [|gradBeta; gradSigSq|] |> DenseVector
```

Why is the assignment to `thetam` causing problems? Is there a magic way to perform updates without mutability?

Here is the complete script:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Charting
open FSharp.Core.Operators
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double
open MathNet.Numerics.Random
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics

let beta, sigSq = 3., 9.
let xt = DenseVector [|23.; 78.; 43.; 32.; 90.; 66.; 89.; 34.; 72.; 99.|]
let T = xt.Count

let genProc () =
    beta * xt + DenseVector [|for i in 1 .. T do yield Normal.Sample(0., Math.Sqrt(sigSq))|]

let llNormal (yt : Vector<float>) (xt : Vector<float>) (beta : float) (sigSq : float) =
    let T = (float yt.Count)
    let z = (yt - beta * xt) / Math.Sqrt(sigSq)
    -0.5 * log (2. * Math.PI) - 0.5 * log (sigSq) - z*z/2./T/sigSq

let grad (yt : Vector<float>) (xt : Vector<float>) (beta : float) (sigSq : float) =
    let T = (float yt.Count)
    let gradBeta = (yt - beta * xt)*xt / sigSq
    let gradSigSq = -0.5*T/sigSq + 0.5/sigSq**2.*(yt - beta * xt)*(yt - beta * xt)
    [|gradBeta; gradSigSq|] |> DenseVector

let hess (yt : Vector<float>) (xt : Vector<float>) (beta : float) (sigSq : float) = 
    let T = (float yt.Count)
    let z = yt - beta * xt
    let h11 = -xt*xt/sigSq
    let h22 = T*0.5/sigSq/sigSq - z*z/sigSq/sigSq/sigSq
    let h12 = -1./sigSq**2.*((yt - beta * xt)*xt)
    array2D [[h11;h12];[h12;h22]] |> DenseMatrix.ofArray2

let yt = genProc()

// until convergence
let mutable thetam = [|beta; sigSq|] |> DenseVector
let mutable gm = grad yt xt beta sigSq

while gm*gm > 0.0001 do
    gm <- grad yt xt beta sigSq
    // 'gm' here is complaining upon equation being assigned to thetam
    thetam <- thetam - (hess yt xt beta sigSq).Inverse() * gm
```

Comment: Is it possible to get working code with some data? It's a bit difficult to track what are the actual types. If your types are actually correct, there is a possibility that you might need to say  `[|gradBeta; gradSigSq|] |> DenseVector.OfArray` as mathnet sometimes changes stuff in-place and sometimes copies the contents.

Comment: @s952163 I think you're right about the DenseVector.OfArray . Please post as answer and I'll hit checkmark.

Comment: that was fast. What timezone are you in? Would you be able to vote for the matnet/mathdotnet tag [alias](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mathnet/synonyms)? Thx!

Comment: I'm in nyc. Just tried voting but it didn't accept since I don't meet the required score on that tag. Thanks for all the help btw. Much appreciated.

Comment: `(hess yt xt beta sigSq).Inverse()` -> `((hess yt xt beta sigSq).Inverse() :?> DenseMatrix)`

Comment: @PetSerAl that should work too. Can you post it as an answer as that's more visible than a comment (and possible to upvote).

Answer (score 0):

You should change at least  `let mutable thetam = [|beta; sigSq|] |> DenseVector` to
`let mutable thetam = [|beta; sigSq|] |> DenseVector.ofArray` (and possibly other `DenseVector` references). Mathnet for performance reasons does in-place changes so it might trip you if you use mutable references:

> DenseVector(Double[] storage)
>
> Create a new dense vector directly binding to a raw array. The array
>   is used directly without copying. Very efficient, but changes to the
>   array and the vector will affect each other.

Versus:

> DenseVector OfArray(Double[] array)
>
> Create a new dense vector as a copy of the given array. This new
>   vector will be independent from the array. A new memory block will be
>   allocated for storing the vector.

In fact we've seen this behavior in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237861/functionalizing-numerical-code)  when `Exponential.Samples` behaved in a similar fashion.

The API docs (while not super user-friendly) are [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm).